# C# CODE to click OK button in Excel popup window?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup

Please see the attached image! I tried below code ALERT and it did not work.

driver.SwitchTo().Alert().

In our application if i click Excel Export button; it opens Excel popup window with OK and Cancel button. How to write a code to recognize this window and click "OK" in C SHARP C#?[image]

Comment: This is simple Desktop Automation. There are pre-existing solutions for that. Do not try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Excel can be automated directlly with interop. But you might not need Excel at all...

Comment: There are many options: 1. Check [X] Do this automatically... 2. You can download the file to temp folder, and start the excel process with this file as arg. 3. Use some automation library like AHK, or even just winapi to find the window with title "Open {filename} with...", and simulate a click on OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the process handles and then compare the titles. If you find the matching title, send a close message to the window. In below code, instead of 'MyExcel' put your window title.

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process process in processlist)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle) && 
        process.MainWindowTitle.Contains("MyExcel"))
      {
           process.CloseMainWindow();
      }
}
```